# .net SqlConnection closes by itself

Tags: .net, sql, database, sqlconnection

I have a static class handling my DB access.
When I open an SqlConnection and access it multithreadedly - it closes by itself after 1-2 queries.
Nowhere in my code I close it - any thoughts???

Thank you
Waldo

Comment: Not enough information, some code to show would be great ;)

Comment: Are you saying that you're sharing a *single* connection between multiple threads? That won't work without a ton of locking code.

Comment: Btw, when you say you access it in multiple threads, do you synchronize properly?

Comment: OK... I was stupid... It was  multithreaded with a single connection... You solved my problem :-)

Comment: If you are worried about performance, the .Net framework automatically implements connection pooling for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=VS.90).aspx.

Answer (score 2):

> When I open an SqlConnection and access it multithreadedly

Then don't access it "multithreadedly" - it's not thread-safe.  Instead, open/close it on each thread, preferably with a using statement.

[MSDN indicates that instance methods of this class are not thread-safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx).